# Is there a way to create a Django migrations not in the last position?

Tags: django, django-models, migration

suppose that this is the migrations history to my project:

```
 [X] 0001_initial
      .
      .
      .
 [X] 0010_auto_20211202_0923
 [X] 0011_auto_20211202_1050
 [X] 0012_auto_20211202_1240
 [X] 0013_auto_20211202_1522
 [X] 0014_auto_20211202_1534
 [X] 0015_auto_20211202_1555
 [X] 0016_auto_20211202_1567
      .
      .
      .
 [X] 0021_data_migration
```

I would like to create a new migration in the middle of the history, between 000_13 and 000_14.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to back migrate to 0013, create a new migration and then refactor all name and dependency and migrate again.

```
python manage.py migrate appname 0013_auto_20211202_1522

python manage.py makemigrations

python manage.py migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

idk if that's possible.

You could just reverse your migrations and start again?

python manage.py migrate appname zero

python manage.py makemigrations

python manage.py migrate

Then you'd start from 0001 again.